nested "if and" statements in excel
I have the below table and have an 2 "IF AND" statement there:

May I ask, if I would like to combine the "IF AND" statement together, how should I go about it? What I am trying to do is to combine the "B" and "S" as a control flag in one statement. All ideas are welcome. Thanks and have a good day.

I don't understand your question: are you asking how to use the test for "B" and "S" in one statement, combined with IF so it's GROUP 1 if Category is B or S? Something like IF(AND(B<C, OR(A2="B", A2="S))[....]. This way if the category is B or S and the date1 is < date 2, then New category is Group 1
